# Django Fargate. The requested resource was not found on this server

Tags: django, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have seem The requested resource was not found on this server, like a thousand times but none of the awnser match my problem.

I made this app from statch, and add a Dockerfile for it.

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /www
COPY requirements.txt /www/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /www/

EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:80" ]
```

Then i run this:
docker build -t pasquin-django-mainapp .
docker run pasquin-django-mainapp

I did that in my local environment, not woking. Y push this Dcokerfile to ECR and then use it in ECS + Fargate, same bada result. I dont know what else todo.

Somebody, help! thanks!

ps: From docker-compose works just marvelous!